# Wp_query Add specific pending posts

Tags: wp-query, post-status

I want to retrieve in archive all the posts with post_status-> publish and those with post_status->pending of specific user.

That's where i'm now:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
    array(
        'post_status' =>'pending',
        'author' => 2),
    array(
        'post_status' =>'publish',
        'author' => 'any'),
    'relation' => 'OR' ,                    
   'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'paged' )
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you try it? What does it output?

Comment: only the publish posts, none of the pending (from author 2)

Comment: Nothing :( Shows only the publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup isn't supported by `WP_Query`.

One approach is to use the `posts_where` filter of `WP_Query` (*there are other ways possible, like collecting post ID's instead from different queries.*) to adjust the SQL query.

To avoid string replaces we could use for example:

```
$custom_query_args = [
   'post_type'   => 'post',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
];

// Add filter
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_where' );

// Query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// Remove filter
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_where' );
```

where our custom filter callback is:

```
function wpse_where( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;
    return $where . " OR ( 
             {wpdb->posts}.post_author = 2 
        AND  {wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
        AND  {wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post'           
    ) ";
}
```

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that i cant do it by using Wp_query.

Comment: I made it by collecting all ids (with get_posts), then merged and finally wp_query with 'post__in'

Comment: Glad to hear you worked it through @Cito